# How to save order comment programmatically in magento2?

Tags: sales-order, magento2.2, quote, php-7, sales-quote

1)I'm creating custom order comment text box in **sales->order->create new order .**

2) Created **order_comment** column in **sales_ order grid/quote**.

3) I need to save order comment text box value into db.How to save comment in **sales_order grid/quote** table?

If anyone knows please explain me?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $order`

Either use the order, or load it separately with

```
$comment = 'Add the comment you need...';
$order = $this->order->get(1); // Load your order
$order->addStatusHistoryComment($comment)
    ->setIsCustomerNotified(false)
    ->setEntityName('order')
    ->save();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: geting error "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magento22`.`sales_order_status_history`, CONSTRAINT `SALES_ORDER_STATUS_HISTORY_PARENT_ID_SALES_ORDER_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `sales_order` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CAS), query was: INSERT INTO `sales_order_status_history` (`is_customer_notified`, `comment`, `status`, `entity_name`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",

Comment: This can't work, because addStatusHistoryComment() returns a OrderStatusHistoryInterface object, so the following methods in your snippets are not chainable.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way

```php
// better to init related instances in __construct
$factory = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
    ->get(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Status\HistoryFactory::class);
$repository = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
    ->get(\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderStatusHistoryRepositoryInterface::class);

// $order - your order instance
$history = $factory->create();
$history->setParentId($order->getId())
    ->setComment('Your Comment')
    ->setStatus($order->getStatus())
    ->setIsVisibleOnFront(0)
    ->setIsCustomerNotified(0);

$repository->save($history);
```